# Elastic Beanstalk Python requirements.txt install from local .whl file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, requirements.txt

I have a simple Elastic Beanstalk Python instance that is installing flask using a requirements.txt file that looks like this

```
Flask==1.0.2
```

This works, but in the interests of speed I am trying to instead use a predownloaded wheel `.whl` file to install.

I have tried putting the `.whl` file in the /opt/python/current/wheels/flask.whl requirements.txt like this...

```
-f /opt/python/current/app/wheels Flask==1.0.2
```

But this is not working, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try putting just /opt/python/current/wheels/flask.whl in the requirements.txt.
Link to official document - https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file

Answer (score 0):

#### Overview:

**[wheel](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/)** is unique in that it doesn't show in `requirements.txt` since the `pip freeze` command lists all installed packages in the current environment whereas `wheel` is a package related to the packaging and distribution of Python packages, rather than a package that your code imports and uses.

Consider SSH'ing to your Beanstalk EC2 instance and check the path of the default **`wheel`** via:

```bash
$ pip show wheel

Name: wheel
Version: 0.42.0
Summary: A built-package format for Python
Home-page: None
Author: None
Author-email: Daniel Holth <dholth@fastmail.fm>
License: None
Location: /home/$USER/app-code-repo/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

---

#### Solution:

You likely need a **[Beanstalk Platform Extension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)** `predeploy` hook to run a simple script to install your local wheel.

- To accomplish the following (you could test first over SSH to the EC2) :

```bash
$ pip install /path/to/your_wheel_file.whl
```

- You would then add the following directory & file to your app source bundle as `.platform/hooks/prebuild/01_install_local_py_wheel.sh` with content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1. run a pip install as a prebuild hook
# please ensure you are in correct pip environment for beanstalk
# and to edit the path to your local whl

echo -e "Installing local wheel"
pip install /path/to/your_wheel_file.whl
```